# How to edit login page in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, login-control

Ok, just got into using joomla at the request of a client.

Joomla! 1.5.23 Stable
Template : safecombonia

Not so familiar with it. So here goes. I managed to have some page which requires registered members only. If user isn't logged in it goes to a page that requires the user to login [index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5ncmVlbmVjb25vbXkucGgvaW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fY29udGVudCZ2aWV3PWFydGljbGUmaWQ9MTMyJkl0ZW1pZD0xMDg=]

[image]

I know this isn't the regular login page because it tracks current user's whereabouts on a page, and if it requires a login for registered users, after successful login it takes the user to that specific page the user was on to continue.

Not so sure if this has already been posted elsewhere, tried looking it up but it's hundreds of related post and I could be looking for a needle in a haystack. Perhaps, anyone can point me to that answered question it would help a lot.

Any ideas where I might find this page to edit that message. I want to add more text there and perhaps a direct link to a sign up or register page for a new user.

Thanks for the help guys. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this by going to **administrator** and in the **menu manager** find the menu which you assigned for it. After find you menu item **edit** that menu, then on the right side you will find **Basic Option**, In this section see there is option called **Login Description Text**. You can see your previous description here just edit it and save and it's done.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But since the request to view the page which I set to registered members only, returned a different login page with that extra text on top as in the image provided. 
index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5ncmVlbmVjb25vbXkucGgvaW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fY29udGVudCZ2aWV3PWFydGljbGUmaWQ9MTMyJkl0ZW1pZD0xMDg=

Not sure if I have properly described it, still stuck with this one. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the file you will want to edit if you intend on making style or layout changes to the login page.

```
components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
```

...

The file that contains the functions for the login page and that I would not recommend editing is:

```
components/com_users/views/view.html.php
```

Comment: if you want to modify the template, you'd better create a template override in your templates/html folder, unless you use template overrides or custom templates, you'll simply lose all your changes after the next joomla update